# The code only prints the first line of the text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop, text-files

I Think the problem is in the nested function Dis_Details()
What im trying to do is to print every line in a text file but when i run the code it only runs the 1 index in the text file and doesnt go beyond that.(if there is nothing on the next line of text file it should stop but its not working properly)

````
def Customer_Details():

    Name = input('Enter the customer name: ')
    Phone = input('Enter the customer phone number: ')

    with open('Customer Details.txt', '+a')as Details:
        Details.write('\n'+Name)
        Details.write(', '+Phone)
        
    Details.close()

    print('Data Saved... Returning to Main menu')
    time.sleep(1)
    Main()


def Recall_Details():

    def Dis_Details():
        Empty = False
        num = 0
        with open('Customer Details.txt','r+')as details:
        
            for line in details:

                Info = details.readlines()

                if not line:
                    break
                else:
                    print('Customer '+str(num)+': '+Info[num])
                    num += 1
                    
                
        details.close()

            

    Choice = input('would you like to check customer Details?(y): ')
    if Choice == 'y':

        Dis_Details()
    ```

Unfortunately i have lost the rest of this code and dont know how to make it better
````

Comment: Why are you doing `for line in details:`, then inside of the loop `Info = details.readlines()`?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: So should i just do ```Info = details.read()``` instead?(i just tried it out but now it only prints the first letter of the line in the text file)

Comment: It seems like you should just get rid of the `Info = details.readlines()` line, then use `print('Customer '+str(num)+': '+ line)` later.

Comment: thanks for all the help i have solved it with the help of akive (Prune i will try my best to reformat my questions in the future to avoid any misunderstandings and help the community help me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('Customer Details.txt','r+') as details:
    for num, line in enumerate(details.read().split("\n")):
        print('Customer ' + str(num) + ': '+ line)
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: Thanks i just tested it it worked perfectly(i have to wait one minute to be able to accept the answer)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to obtain an array of read lines then work with that, in this case you just need to:

```
def dis_details(path):
    lines = []
    with open(path) as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        print(f"Costumer {i}: {lines[i]}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this worked fine as well(i already accepted akivas as it was simpler for me to understand)